# Add string in a certain interval position in Python

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, list

I have string like this `718868538ddwe`. I want to insert back slash (`"\"`) at interval of 3.

I need output like this: `718\868\538\ddw\e`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `str.join` with a list comprehension:

```
x = '718868538ddwe'
res = '\\'.join([x[3*i: 3*(i+1)] for i in range(len(x) // 3 + 1)])

print(res)
# 718\868\538\ddw\e
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def chunks(input_str):
    current = input_str
    while current:
        next, current = current[:3], current[3:]
        yield next

str = ''.join([chunk + '/' for chunk in chunks(input_str)])
```

Comment: li = textwrap.wrap(dst,3)